# KSQLDB rest api does create stream with definition work?(Confluent operator)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

When using rest api with KsqlDB when trying to create a stream with definition, I see no error and it doesn't create a stream.

```
  "sql": "CREATE STREAM  user_test_EKS(userId DOUBLE, name VARCHAR)  WITH (kafka_topic='user_EKS', value_format='json', partitions=1);",
  "streamsProperties": {
      "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
  }
}
```

However, this query body does work as expected

```
{
  "ksql": "CREATE STREAM pageviews_home AS SELECT * FROM pageviews_original WHERE pageid='home'; CREATE STREAM pageviews_alice AS SELECT * FROM pageviews_original WHERE userid='alice';",
  "streamsProperties": {
    "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. You say that you are using "rest api" for both cases what does not make sense...

Comment: Your `"sql"` field needs to be called `"ksql"` like in the second request